# SVN could not connect to server

Tags: subversion

I have got an issue while updating svn repository from my server. See the error below

```
SVN: OPTIONS of 'http://ipaddress/svn/folder': could not connect to server (http://ipaddress)
```

but i can to ping and connect SVN server via ssh.

Comment: Can you please provide your svn command line? This would appear to be an issue with your SVN server not running or accepting connections.

Comment: The issue is with the **WEB SERVER**... *http://...* means `svn` is trying to talk to a webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can SSH to your server, you should be using `svn+ssh` URLs, not `http` URLs. Try something like this:

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://myuser@ipaddress/svn/folder checkoutlocation
```

If your login name is the same on both machines (`myuser` in this example) and don't need the checkout directory to be named differently, you can shorten the command:

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://ipaddress/svn/folder
```

This tells Subversion to tunnel the SVN protocol over SSH. HTTP is an entirely separate protocol, and requires that you set up Subversion to work with Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Your Web server is not responding. I would:

- Check that your Web server is running.
- Check that it is accepting connections from the local host.

If both of those work, it is likely a firewall issue.